# Laravel form face use $key => $value ($value2) instead of $key => $value

Tags: php, laravel, forms, facade, pluck

Sorry if the title is misleading...

I have the following to create a select box using the laravel Form facade:

```
{{ Form::select('category_select', $categories_select, null, array('class' => 'selectpicker show-tick', 'data-live-search' => 'true', 'id' => 'category_select')) }}
```

Now `$catgories_select` is a `pluck()` of **id** and **name**.

I want to do the same for another select (Tax rules) but there I want to have it like the following:

`<option value="id">$value1 ($value2)</option>`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you `pluck` the models before the view, you'll need two collections. But you could just do one query, then pluck inline. Let's assume `$categories` is your queried collection before the `pluck`:

```
{{ Form::select('category_select', $categories->pluck('name', 'id'), null) }}
```

Then on the other you'd `pluck` a mutated property:

```
{{ Form::select('category_select_tax', $categories->pluck('compositeName', 'id'), null) }}
```

And then, on your `Category` model you'd have:

```
public function getCompositeNameAttribute()
{
    return "{$this->name} ({$this->value2})";
}
```